# How to stop function to executing more than once in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in javascript and jquery. One of my functions are executing itself while calling another one. I tried every method I could find here to stop this. But then this function stops executing completely while applying them. I need it to execute only once.

I was trying to populate a list from a javascript array. The first function is for that. Then I need to add more items to this array and populate the list with the new array. The second function addProcessFunc() is for that. But while executing the second function the items from the first function is added once more to the array. I need that to be stopped.

My code is as follows:-

HTML:-

```
<div class="container">
    <label id="processError" class="validationError"></label>
    <div class="process">
        <div class="tab-content addProcess">
            <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <div class="addProcessDiv">
                <label>Process Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="processName" name="processName" class="form-control processName" />
                <button type="submit" onclick="addProcessFunc()" class="btn addButton">Add</button>
            <div class="sortList">
                <ul id="appendHere"></ul>                                  
                        <div class="saveBtn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn">Save</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var processArray = [];
    $("document").ready(function(){ //I need this to be executed only once.
            processArray.push({
                id: i,
                processName: Some_Process
            });
            console.log(processArray);
            $("#testTemplate").tmpl(processArray).appendTo("#appendHere");
    });
    function addProcessFunc(){
        var name = document.getElementById('processName').value;
        if (name != ""){
            i++
                processArray.push({
                    id: i,
                    processName: Another_Process
                });
                console.log(processArray);
            $("#testTemplate").tmpl(processArray).appendTo("#appendHere");
        } else {
            document.getElementById('processError').innerHTML = "Required";
        }
    }
</script>   
<script id="testTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            <span class="sort drag-handle"></span>
                <label class="sortLabelLeft">${processName}</label>
            <span class="delete"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

Comment: can you state your problem little clear and what area trying to achieve

Comment: `$("document")` try replacing it with `$(document)` though I would be surprised if this is causing the problem

Comment: Where is `i` defined? Why not use a named function for the `processArray.push` through to the `appendTo`? This may help simplify which tends to lead to solving things.

Comment: To be honest, he doesn't even need $(document), using jQuery he can replace it with $() and it'll achieve the same effect. I'd be interested to know where the tmpl is coming into all of this as I don't see it declared. But the easiest/laziest way would be having a global variable set to false, a check around the function to see if the global variable is false, run the function, then update the global to true thus prevent it from executing again. But thats the lazy way round.

Comment: @Karthikeyansundaramoorthi added details about my problem.

Comment: @gurvinder372 tried as you said. but no change.

Comment: @ArjunAjith replace `type="submit"` with `type="button"`

Comment: @gurvinder372 Tried that too.. No effect..

Comment: @ArjunAjith can you share a fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This adds only one item to list which is added, Problem is you have declared the array outside so each time the element is duplicated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i=1;
    $("document").ready(function(){ //I need this to be executed only once.
        var processArray = [];
            Some_Process = 'test';
            processArray.push({
                id: i,
                processName: Some_Process
            });
            console.log(processArray);
            $("#testTemplate").tmpl(processArray).appendTo("#appendHere");
    });
    function addProcessFunc(){
        var processArray = [];
        var name = document.getElementById('processName').value;
        if (name != ""){
            i++
                processArray.push({
                    id: i,
                    processName: name
                });
                console.log(processArray);
            $("#testTemplate").tmpl(processArray).appendTo("#appendHere");
        } else {
            document.getElementById('processError').innerHTML = "Required";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** In your specific case, have a look at Karthikeyan sundaramoorthi answer

---

For future reference, general solution :

```js
// you want this function to be executed not more than once
function myFunction() {
  if(!this.done) {
    this.done = true;
    console.log("I'm running");
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```